# Почему не работает NSOperationQueue.mainQueue?

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть код

```
    @IBAction func joinButtonTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
        self.joinButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.resultLogIn.text = "Происходит проверка данных..."
        })


    var response = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.SendRequest("<Command=LogIn><Login=\(loginTextField.text!)><Password=\(passwordTextField.text!)>")
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы ДО того, как начнется загрузка данных о пользователе, у меня начинал работать `activityIndicator`. Но этого не происходит. Почему? Я ведь занусул его в UI поток. Он начинает крутиться уже после загрузки данных.
**SendRequest:**

```
func SendRequest(request: String) -> String
{
    var response = ""
    var bigData: [UInt8] = []
    var (success, errmsg) = client.connect(timeout: 1)
    if success {
        var (success, errmsg) = client.send(str: request + "\n" )
        if success {
            while(true) {
                var data = client.read(1024*10)
                if (data == nil) {
                    break
                }
                bigData.appendContentsOf(data!)
            }
        }
        else {
            print(errmsg)
        }
    }
    else {
        print(errmsg)
    }
    var bytes = NSData.init(bytes: bigData, length: bigData.count)
    if let str = String(data: bytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String? {
        print(str)
        response = str
    }
    return response
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включить таймер можно без NSOperationQueue. В NSOperationQueue лучше включить SendRequest, а в основную очередь после скачивания добавить выключение таймера.

Более подробно можно почитать здесь: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-concurrency/

```
@IBAction func joinButtonTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.joinButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.resultLogIn.text = "Происходит проверка данных..."
    NSOperationQueue.addOperationWithBlock{ () -> Void in
        var response = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.SendRequest("<Command=LogIn><Login=\(loginTextField.text!)><Password=\(passwordTextField.text!)>")
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })
    } 
}
```